# Convert Cell to an Array

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have a cell array with dimensions 1x16384 consists of 16384 numbers.
I tried using `cell2mat()`, but i get one element with all those numbers in it.
How do i convert it to an array with 1x16384 dimension.

> Assuming B= cell2mat(A);

A looks like;

```
Columns 16382 through 16384

    '15.849'    '16.337'    '14.872'
```

where as B looks like;

```
B =

-8.921-8.433-2.5745.23911.58714.02811.5876.7041.821-1.109-2.085-1.5970.3562.
```

console ;
    class(A), class(A{1}), size(A), size(A{1})

```
ans =

cell


ans =

char


ans =

           1       16384


ans =

     1     6
```

For mcve,
[Csv input file](https://app.box.com/s/z9boehttt8gu0vy709orlh74n2t8lzxf)

```
DELIMITER = ' ';
HEADERLINES = 3;

% Import the file
newData1 = importdata('C:\Python34\co2a0000364.csv', DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end


new = textdata(6:16452,4);
A = new;

for z = 1:63
    A(i*257)=[];
end

B = A'
A= B;
A= cell2mat(B)
B= A
```

Comment: It would help if you posted an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post the following information from the output of your command prompt, assuming your cell array is called `A`: `class(A)`, `class(A{1})`, `size(A)`, `size(A{1})`.  Your post is lacking **a lot** of information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @kkuilla i have reedited the question. I hope this helps!

Comment: @HarshSharma - That doesn't really answer my questions.  I don't know what your original input data looks like.  Can you please update your post with what I asked of you?

Comment: @rayryeng, i have attached the input data file sir.

Comment: @HarshSharma - That wasn't what I asked.  Never mind.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng sorry man. class(A) - Cell, Class(A{1}) - char, size (A) - 1 16384, size{A(1) is - 1 6

Comment: in the line `A = cell2mat(B)`, could you show us what `B` looks like, and what `A` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You way of importing data is quite clumsy. I invite you to read the [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function documentation, which allows much more flexibility in importing mixed data type (text and numeric data).

I propose you another way of importing, which uses `textscan`:

```
%% // Import only the 4th column of data
fid = fopen('co2a0000364.csv') ;
M = textscan( fid , '%*s%*s%*s%f' , 'Delimiter',' ' , 'HeaderLines',4) ;
fclose(fid) ;
M = cell2mat(M) ;

%% // reshape to have each channel in its own colum
M = reshape( M , 257 , [] ) ;

%% // Delete the channel number from the data table
M(1,:) = [] ;
```

This will give you a nice 256*64 matrix, containing the data for each of the 64 channels in one column.

if you really want them all in sequence in one column, just add:

```
M = M(:) ;
```

to the end of the code.

---

Explanation note: the `textscan` format specifier I use: `'%*s%*s%*s%f'` tells the function to read 4 elements per line:
- 3x strings : `%s`
- 1x floating point number: `%f`

adding the character `*` in the format specifier (for example `%*s`) for an element tells the function to **ignore** the element, so it does not put it into the output.

Comment: Thank you so much Hoki, this was very informative, and it will surely help me in future too, thanks again.